# How to compile a draft android studio from the bash or bat?

Tags: android, automation

From the editor I can compile directly but would like to automate doing this from a script in bash. How do I can do ?, how I can compile the solution with jks key?

Or what are the commands to go?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: 
https://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html

change build.gradle:

```
...
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig { ... }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("myreleasekey.keystore")
            storePassword "password"
            keyAlias "MyReleaseKey"
            keyPassword "password"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
...
```

And compile:

```
$ ./gradlew assembleRelease
```